# Gulp optimize images with imagemin

Tags: gulp, gulp-imagemin, imagemin

I'm trying to Gulp optimize my images with imagemin

https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-image-optimization

I have problem to find a good documentation which can show me exact parameters and different option. For now there is not a lot of gain in my optimization:

```
var imageop = require('gulp-image-optimization');
var pngquant = require('imagemin-pngquant');
var imageminJpegoptim = require('imagemin-jpegoptim');

var baseUrl = "web/assets/";
var imgSrc = baseUrl + "src/images/";
var imgDist = baseUrl + "dist/images/";

gulp.task('img', function(cb) {
    gulp.src([imgSrc + '**/*.png', imgSrc + '**/*.jpg', imgSrc + '**/*.gif', imgSrc + '**/*.jpeg'])
        .pipe(imageop({
            optimizationLevel: 10,
            progressive: true,
            interlaced: true,
            use: [pngquant(), imageminJpegoptim()]
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(imgDist)).on('end', cb).on('error', cb);
});
```

Did I missed something in the config?

Comment: Side note: you can tighten up your `gulp.src` with `imgSrc + '**/*.(png|jpg|gif|jpeg)'` (though if you follow my answer you don't have to specify the file extensions)

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you have reasons to expect more significant size decreases than you're getting. In that case, my bet is the trouble is old tech.

The `gulp-image-optimization` you're using appears to rely on the old `imagemin`, which hadn't broken each type of optimization into its own plugin (I say "appears" because it's years old, that's what's reflected in `gulp-image-optimization`'s documentation, and that's how `imagemin` used to work if I'm remembering right).

The recommended plugin these days, and the one linked in [`imagemin`](https://github.com/imagemin/imagemin)'s documentation, is [`gulp-imagemin`](https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-imagemin).

Using `gulp-imagemin`, your basic setup will be something like

```js
const gulp = require('gulp'),
      imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin');

gulp.task('default', (cb) =>
    gulp.src('src/images/*')
        .pipe(imagemin())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/images')).on('end', cb).on('error', cb)
);
```

(That code taken directly from the `gulp-imagemin` documentation, with your error callback added.)

`gulp-imagemin` includes plugins for png([`optipng`](https://github.com/imagemin/imagemin-optipng))  and jpg ([`jpegtran`](https://github.com/imagemin/imagemin-jpegtran)) optimization by default.